# Find date and time of past events

Tags: data-request, media, search-engine, news

I am looking for an efficient way to find exact date and time for events in the recent past which have been in the news. Finding the date is not difficult, but I am also interested in the exact time the event has first been reported in the media and as such been made available to the public.

As an example, the WHO has announced on 11 March 2020 that the Covid-19 outbreak is now considered a pandemic, that's easy to find in press statements or on news sites, but I spent hours trying to find the time when the media briefing started and/or when it was first reported in the news. I have a whole list of such events, and I am hoping to speed up the research.

Is anyone aware of websites or tools that can provide such information on date and time? Or a good strategy? I tried google search, google news, websites of big media, wikipedia articles, original press statements, ...

Comment: I can give you a big list of what doesn't work. And being in the retrospective reconstruction of events business myself I should point out the obvious: Bloomberg or Refinitiv. They provide provenance data including timestamps and topic identifiers. but alas, not open data. Not even the identifiers are somehow usable outside of their products.